# Does magnetic field exist throughout space?

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, geomagnetism, soft-matter, interstellar-matter

My question is quite subjective and I could not find a suitable explanation to whether there is a magnetic field in space beyond earth .I read one of the article stating

---

### Interstellar dust clouds have been found with fields as high as a few milli Gauss; about 1000 times stronger than the Milky Ways average magnetic field. As these clouds collapse, the fields are amplified, and some theoreticians believe that magnetic fields may actually support many 'molecular clouds' against rapid collapse. That's why there seem to be so many of these otherwise unstable clouds in interstellar space.
On the cosmological scale, there is no data to suggest that magnetic fields are present. They certainly are not important in the dynamics of the universe for any reasonable range of field strengths consistent with present observational constraints.

My doubt is whether magnetic field in space impacts our life on earth and how do interstellar clouds have magnetic field ,how did it originate.is it because of charges and ions?

Comment: Light exists in free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the cosmological scale, there is no data to suggest that magnetic fields are present.

On the other hand, theory tells us that magnetic fields are everywhere. When a magnetic field is created, it propagates outward at the speed of light and never stops. Also, any magnetic field present in the early universe would have been vastly stretched across cosmological distances by Universal expansion.

But magnetic fields decay very sharply with distance, with a cube law which is more severe than the square law which governs the fading of *electro-*magnetic radiation with distance. So on cosmological scales, such magnetic fields will be so faint that detection becomes impossible. This explains why no data on them can be collected.

A magnetic field is created whenever an electrical charge moves. So all you need to create one is some ionized material and some effect which sends electrons and ions in different directions. In cosmology, the commonest cause is ionizing radiation - ultraviolet, X rays or gamma rays. Stars also create strong local magnetic fields, which they can sometimes fling out into space. Black holes and supernovae are good sources of the necessary ingredients; time and Universal expansion do the rest (ironically, paradoxically or beautifully to choice, dying magnetic fields being swallowed by the black hole are our best candidate for the flingers of matter and radiation to create new magnetic fields).

The only magnetic fields strong enough to affect life on Earth are the ones flung out by the Sun in solar flares. These can penetrate our own Van Allen field belts, causing bursts of radiation and on occasion even disabling ground-based power lines and orbiting satellites.

Answer (score 1):

A charged object changes the magnetic field in the space around it as it moves.

In terms of classical electricity and magnetism, the electric and magnetic fields are inextricably linked in a way described by Maxwell's equations. They describe that the motion of electric charge *induces* a change in the magnetic field.

When electricity is transmitted from power-plants, they use *Alternating Current* AC because a changing electric current can readily induce a magnetic field. This way they can transmit power with a high voltage and low current (for efficiency) and then efficiently *transform* the power to lower voltage (for safety) with a higher current. This transformation occurs in the "transformer"... I know, very creative.

I bring up that example because it is well understood that on earth, just like in outer space, the movement of charge induces magnetic fields. It's the same phenomenon whether  it's electrons in a copper wire or plasma ejected from a star.*

*All of this gets a bit more complicated either to model in terms of quantum mechanics or to observe from great distances.